# Why is splat in arrays so costly?

Tags: arrays, ruby, performance

I love using splat to build arrays and hashes:

- they are array and hash literals, so you don't have to follow some computation to see what kind of value you get, the syntax is very clear
- they make it easy to build quite complex values in a single expression, instead of using a more imperative style (that, yes, you can turn into a single assignment with things like `tap`, but it's less readable).

However splatting is costly.

```rb
require 'benchmark'

$array = (0...100).to_a

n = 100_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('add   ') {n.times{$array + $array + $array}}
  x.report('splat ') {n.times{[*$array, *$array, *$array]}}
end
```

On Machine A (MRI 3.1.3) I have:

```
          user     system      total        real
add     0.031583   0.001421   0.033004 (  0.033006)
splat   0.050174   0.001397   0.051571 (  0.051584)
```

On Machine B (MRI 2.7.4):

```
          user     system      total        real
add     0.278377   0.000000   0.278377 (  0.278316)
splat   0.780735   0.043730   0.824465 (  0.824377)
```

How come splat-based array construction is so slow?  I expect splat-based construction to be no slower than plain addition (after all the AST could even turn one into the other), and I actually expect it to be more efficient (since the language can see everything, so it can avoid the intermediate arrays created by binary addition, it can also anticipate the size of the final array and reserve the space upfront, etc.).

So how come the alternative, that go throw a method call (so, a priori, less optimizable by the interpreter), are faster than something in which everything is honestly exposed to the interpreter?

### EDIT: more alternatives

```rb
require 'benchmark/ips'

ary = (0...100).to_a

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('add')          {ary + ary + ary}
  x.report('append')       {res = ary.dup; res.append(*ary); res.append(*ary); res}
  x.report('concat2')      {res = []; res.concat(ary); res.concat(ary); res.concat(ary); res}
  x.report('concat3')      {[].concat(ary, ary, ary)}
  x.report('concat_splat') {[].concat(*[ary, ary, ary])}
  x.report('flatten')      {[ary, ary, ary].flatten}
  x.report('flatten(1)')   {[ary, ary, ary].flatten(1)}
  x.report('splat')        {[*ary, *ary, *ary]}
  x.compare!
end
```

This is Machine A, MRI 3.1.3.

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
                 add   300.630k i/100ms
              append   140.913k i/100ms
             concat2   154.698k i/100ms
             concat3   120.459k i/100ms
        concat_splat   142.808k i/100ms
             flatten    10.329k i/100ms
          flatten(1)    52.207k i/100ms
               splat   195.946k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
                 add      3.040M (± 0.7%) i/s -     15.332M in   5.043760s
              append      1.400M (± 1.9%) i/s -      7.046M in   5.034067s
             concat2      1.532M (± 2.1%) i/s -      7.735M in   5.049821s
             concat3      1.134M (± 2.6%) i/s -      5.782M in   5.101784s
        concat_splat      1.409M (± 1.9%) i/s -      7.140M in   5.068373s
             flatten    102.948k (± 0.6%) i/s -    516.450k in   5.016786s
          flatten(1)    517.582k (± 5.2%) i/s -      2.610M in   5.058161s
               splat      1.939M (± 1.4%) i/s -      9.797M in   5.052514s

Comparison:
                 add:  3039958.8 i/s
               splat:  1939484.0 i/s -  1.57x  (± 0.00) slower
             concat2:  1532384.2 i/s -  1.98x  (± 0.00) slower
        concat_splat:  1409339.8 i/s -  2.16x  (± 0.00) slower
              append:  1400120.7 i/s -  2.17x  (± 0.00) slower
             concat3:  1134080.2 i/s -  2.68x  (± 0.00) slower
          flatten(1):   517582.1 i/s -  5.87x  (± 0.00) slower
             flatten:   102948.3 i/s - 29.53x  (± 0.00) slower
```

Comment: What about `[a, b, c].flatten`?

Comment: At this point benchmarking Ruby 2.7 isn't much use. Ruby 3.0 introduced *significant* performance improvements not possible in Ruby 2.x.

Comment: @tadman Flatten is not equivalent, I don't want to flatten possible members of my subarrays.  And since it needs to check every member, it is anyway slower than the others by far (40x).  And 2.7 is still relevant to me, because of deployments in production where Ruby 3 has not arrived yet.

Comment: @akim how about `flatten(1)`?

Comment: @akim as an important note the results of `append` are different than the others maybe you meant `concat`. Also when I run these tests with `fruity` they are all reasonably equivalent. https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/Ruby-3?s=app#main.rb

Comment: Bummer, you are absolutely right, it should have been concat, not append.  I've edited my question to focus on add and splat only.

Comment: Note that you're running concat but reporting it as append. `x.report('append    ') {n.times{concat}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Addition and splat versions emit different bytecode (some output is omitted for brevity):

```
puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(<<~ADDITION).disasm
  src = (0...100).to_a
  res = src + src + src
ADDITION

0000 putobject                              0...100                   (   1)[Li]
0002 opt_send_without_block                 <calldata!mid:to_a, argc:0, ARGS_SIMPLE>
0004 setlocal_WC_0                          src@0
0006 getlocal_WC_0                          src@0                     (   2)[Li]
0008 getlocal_WC_0                          src@0
0010 opt_plus                               <calldata!mid:+, argc:1, ARGS_SIMPLE>
0012 getlocal_WC_0                          src@0
0014 opt_plus                               <calldata!mid:+, argc:1, ARGS_SIMPLE>
0016 dup
0017 setlocal_WC_0                          res@1
0019 leave
```

vs

```
puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(<<~SPLATS).disasm
  src = (0...100).to_a
  res = [*src, *src, *src]
SPLATS

0000 putobject                              0...100                   (   1)[Li]
0002 opt_send_without_block                 <calldata!mid:to_a, argc:0, ARGS_SIMPLE>
0004 setlocal_WC_0                          src@0
0006 getlocal_WC_0                          src@0                     (   2)[Li]
0008 splatarray                             true
0010 getlocal_WC_0                          src@0
0012 concatarray
0013 getlocal_WC_0                          src@0
0015 concatarray
0016 dup
0017 setlocal_WC_0                          res@1
0019 leave
```

Two snippets above looks quite similar, the difference is 2 `ops_plus` instructions vs `splatarray` + 2 `concatarray`s. But implementation-wise the difference become bigger.

The first one boils down to 2 [`rb_ary_plus`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4f73de67edc18207148fa311eff8f463ac873981/array.c#L5078), in a nutshell:

- allocate memory for src + src
- copy src + src to a new memory location
- allocate memory for (src + src) + src
- copy (src + src) + src to a new memory location

The latter seems to be more complex internally: `splatarray` boils down to `rb_ary_dup` (so we copy ary first), `concatarray` under the hood [duplicates a target array too](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c1ab6ddc9a6fa228caa5d26b118b54855051279c/vm_insnhelper.c#L4662) and then boils down to `rb_ary_splice`; the latter is a bit hairy, but I believe we go to this [branch](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4f73de67edc18207148fa311eff8f463ac873981/array.c#L2351) where we effectively double array capacity (which includes copying the 1st array) and then copy the 2nd array. I'm not 100% sure if I'm tracing this execution flow properly, but if I do it gives us:

- duplicate src
- duplicate src again (?)
- double target capacity (includes copying)
- copy the 2nd array to the space allocated above
- duplicate (src + src)
- double (src + src) capacity (includes copying (src + src) elements to a new memory location)
- copy 3rd array to the allocated space

These additional duplications could explain the difference (not to mention overall complexity of the latter meaning more conditionals checked etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the analysis!  So you do explain why the current implementations have these benchmark profiles.  But I would really like to understand whether it's only that the current implementations are poor, or whether there's a good reason somewhere that explains why it "has" to be slower.

Comment: @akim At a guess it's because that's not the intended use of splat. Splat is when you want to treat the elements as individual values for the purposes of passing them as arguments. You're asking Ruby to treat the Array as individual values and then make a new Array out of those individual values. It probably could be optimized, but the [opportunity cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost?wprov=sfla1) is high.

Comment: @akim `Array#concat` is variadic, and its intended usage is not `a.concat(b).concat(c)` (like in the case in question) but rather `a.concat(b,c,...)` - the latter probably should perform better than the former. Also, you could do `a.concat(*<array of arrays>)` which is not doable with overloaded addition itself, so concat is more convenient in some cases (at a certain price). There might be other reasons too that I don't know (honestly, it's the 1st time I take a look at the Array's internal machinery :))